# jQuery.SerialScroll

Tags: jquery

Please help me, I am stucked. Can not understand how to use this plugin. I have a large home page wich devides by the dives. So i need a fixed arrow down the site to make it scroll my page every div when i push it.
I`ve got this plgin right from here http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html
And the demo with my arrow is right here(the top section) 
http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/serialScroll/

I understand that I should somehow to show the script when to break, but still stucked:(

Thsnx 4 help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I can`t understand, for example i make an arrow with an id next. But how I should say where to go when to stop and where is my divs to show?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#next').trigger( 'next' );       
    });
```

Comment: I still do not know how to make it. There should be a lot of triggers throught one body with a lot of elements/divs/whatever, so when i am coming there the triggers should change